# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer

Tags: asp.net, json

I got this exception error when I change the TimeToSendLocation
can anyone tell me what is the wrong because I'm gonna shot myself

```
    public ReturnObject SetAppSettings(JsonSetting systemSetting)
    {
        try
        {
            Setting updateSetting = model.Settings.FirstOrDefault();

            updateSetting.DelayTolerance = systemSetting.DelayTolerance;
            updateSetting.DashboardRefreshment = systemSetting.DashboardRefreshment;
            updateSetting.NewLocationDistance = systemSetting.NewLocationDistance;
            updateSetting.EndOfWorkTime = systemSetting.EndOfWorkTime.TimeOfDay;
            updateSetting.CheckedInValidation = systemSetting.CheckedInValidation;
            updateSetting.CheckInTolerance = systemSetting.CheckInTolerance;
            updateSetting.AutoSignout = systemSetting.AutoSignout;

            updateSetting.TimeToSendLocation= systemSetting.TimeToSendLocation;

            model.Entry(updateSetting).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            model.SaveChanges();

            return new ReturnObject() { Result = true, Message = "Settings Changed Successfully" };

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ReturnObject() { Result = false, Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

updateSetting is of type 'Setting' and systemSetting is of type "JSONSetting".  they have two different types. it is like assinging a string to an integer. you have to either cast/convert it or make a new object.
soo.. try

```
 updateSetting.TimeToSendLocation= Convert.ToInt32(systemSetting.TimeToSendLocation);
```

Comment: are the two different types of settings compatible?